# use bsdtar to generate zip file

Tags: zip, tar, gnuwin32

i'm using GnuWin32's `bsdtar`, to extract it's simple:

```
bsdtar  xvf c:\test.zip -C  c:\temp\
```

but i failed to create zip files. I tried

```
bsdtar -cf test.zip a.csv b.csv
```

but the generated file couldn't be opened by winzip.

what's the correct way to generate zip file in command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1:

> ```
> -a, --auto-compress
>      (c mode only) Use the archive suffix to decide a set of the for-
>      mat and the compressions.
> ```

So, you would have to use:

```
bsdtar -a -cf test.zip a.csv b.csv
```

Which, in fact, is exactly the example they give:

> ```
> tar -a -cf archive.zip source.c source.h
>      creates a new archive with zip format
> ```

---

Pro tip: everytime you are looking for how to do something with a command that comes from the *NIX world, try typing `man <command>` in Google. This technique never failed me.

Comment: bsdtar: invalid option -- a
Usage:
  List:    bsdtar -tf <archive-filename>
  Extract: bsdtar -xf <archive-filename>
  Create:  bsdtar -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
  Help:    bsdtar --help

Comment: Looks like only the oldest bsdtar don't have this option. According to the [actual, up-to-date documentation](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/ManPageBsdtar1#OPTIONS), the `-a` option exists.

Comment: However, there does not seem to be any other way to create a proper zip archive with bsdtar. If you are on Windows, you could try switching to 7z (the command line version of 7zip), but that would require you to change your commands (especially tedious if you have scripts using it).

Comment: After digging it seems that the GnuWin32 version of bsdtar is indeed seriously outdated. The GnuWin32 website itself states that it is still there "for archeological reasons".

Comment: thx I'll switch to 7zip

Comment: You can try and update to the latest version of libarchive, although I do not know if they have a compiled bsdtar shipped with it. Sorry not to have any other solutions.

Comment: Months later, a BSD TAR.exe was added to Windows 10 (1903) from build 17063 (December, 2017)